# Logging test output of SpecFlow to a CSV file using SeriLog

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, serilog

I have multiple `SpecFlow` feature file(s) and I want to log the `Test Name` `Test Outcome` for my tests. I want to write it in a CSV file and I am using `Serilog` for logging purposes.

```
public class LoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
    {
        Func<string> headerFactory = () => "date time;logtype;environment;ShipTracker build version;test case description;status";
        public Serilog.Core.Logger Create()
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(new CustomCsvLogging(), $"C:\\Dev\\Logs\\shiptracker-ui-{DateTime.Now}log.csv", hooks: new HeaderWriter(headerFactory))
                //.ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();
            return logger;
        }
    }
```

I would like to log into the file in the format mentioned below

```
date time        | logtype |environment| app build version | test case Name| status
----------------------------------------------------------
02-04-2020 4:30 | Test Reults|Mt|2.0.150| Loading Views| Success
02-04-2020 4:31 | Test Reults|Mt|2.0.150| Create new voyage| Failed
```

I have the `Environment`, `App Build Version` in my `Config` file
I want to know how to get the output from The TestRunner and log it. I am okay to implement any custom logger. I have to create a new entry into the CSV file for every test case executed:

[image]

Comment: What are you using for your unit test provider? MS Test? NUnit, xUnit?

Comment: ```SpecFlow Test Runner ```

Comment: Do you want the CSV to be updated after every scenario execution or once after completion of all the scenarios?

Comment: After completion of all scenarios

Comment: Seems like you want to write a Scenario [Hook](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html) that injects a [`ScenarioContext`](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/ScenarioContext.html) which should have some information on the current test run.